# How do you put a computer into Hybrid Sleep?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-7

How do you programmatically put Windows into Hybrid Sleep, ***without*** temporarily changing the settings? (The settings are initially set up such that Sleep goes into standby, and Hibernate goes into hibernate.)

Answer (score 0):

you can use it from command line prompt:

to Shutdown: shutdown.exe

to Lock: Rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation

to Sleep: Rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState Sleep //Hibernate must be OFF

to Hibernate: Rundll32.exe Powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState //Hibernate must be enabled

Comment: Which one does hybrid sleep fit in, exactly?

Comment: @Arrabi: Doesn't that hibernate, according to your post?

Comment: sorry !! my bad , I mean: Rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState Sleep.

Comment: @Arrabi: Doesn't that go into standby?

Comment: can you check the event viewer please to make sure

Comment: @Arrabi: Sorry if this is a bit blunt, but what you're saying doesn't make sense. The word `Sleep` in `Rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState Sleep` is insignificant -- it actually *sets* a hibernate flag, which is not only the opposite of what it says, but also misleading and not what I'm asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
^!Numpad9::DllCall("PowrProf\SetSuspendState", "int", 0, "int", 0, "int", 0)
^!Numpad8::DllCall("PowrProf\SetSuspendState", "int", 1, "int", 0, "int", 0)
```

in [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). You'd then have to press Ctrl+Alt+Numpad9. Ctrl+Alt+Numpad8 is for putting it into hibernation mode.